# Grouping only rows which have a value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this record

```
atmno                          atmid       netpay
------------------------------ ----------- --------
1234123412345                  2           18426.68
NULL                           NULL          527.19
NULL                           NULL         4852.08
1234123412345                  1            4611.70
NULL                           NULL         1531.10
```

I want to group only the rows of the `atmno` which has a value. And for the other columns, i am taking the MIN of atmid and SUM of netpay. The desired output should look like this.

```
atmno                          atmid       netpay
------------------------------ ----------- ---------
1234123412345                  1           23038.38
NULL                           NULL          527.19
NULL                           NULL         4852.08
NULL                           NULL         1531.10
```

This is what I've done so far.

```
SELECT atmno, MIN(atmid), SUM(netpay) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY atmno
```

You probably know that this query will also group the null values. My goal is to attain the desired result with just one query. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use 2 separate select query and then a UNION ALL to combine the result as one

```
SELECT atmno, MIN(atmid), SUM(netpay) 
FROM table 
WHERE atmno IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY atmno

UNION ALL

SELECT atmno, atmid, netpay
FROM   table
WHERE  atmno IS NULL
```

Comment: Guess it really needs to use UNION after all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select atmno, atmid, netpay 
from table t1, (select atmno, min(atmid), netpay
from table where atmno is not null 
group by atmid) t2
where t2.atmno =t1.atmno and t2.atmid = t1.atmid;
order by case when atmno is null then 1 else 0,
atmid
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT atmno,MIN(atmid),SUM(netpay) FROM table 
where atmno is not null group by atmno
UNION ALL
SELECT atmno,atmid,netpay FROM table WHERE atmno IS NULL
```